# How to prove that the Laplace distribution is a sub-exponential distribution random variable

Tags: random-variables

How to prove that a random variable obeying the Laplace distribution is a sub-exponential distribution random variable?

Comment: It has a moment generating function

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how to choose the parameter $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ during the proof to make it satisfy subExp($\lambda$, $\alpha$).

Comment: You don’t need to. Being sub exponential is equivalent to having a moment generating function. If you really want, you can look at the proof, which will give you an explicit choice for the parameters. An alternative approach is that laplace is the difference of two independent exponentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a sub-exponential random variable $X$ with parameters $\nu, \alpha$ states that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]\leq e^{\frac{\nu^2\lambda^2}{2}}$ for $|\lambda|< \frac{1}{\alpha}$. In your case, this means that we essentially need to upper-bound the moment-generating function (MGF) of a Laplace distribution accordingly.

To this end, consider first a centered random variable $X\sim\mathrm{Laplace}(1)$. Its MGF is $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]=\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}$ for $|\lambda| < 1$. From there, you can find many upper-bounds on the MGF of the desired form. For example, you can check that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] \leq e^{2\lambda^2}$ for $|\lambda|<\frac12$, meaning that $X$ is sub-exponential with parameters $\nu=2, \alpha=2$.

If you want to extend the result to the Laplace distribution with parameter $b>0$, you just need to use the fact that if $X\sim\mathrm{Laplace}(1)$, then $bX\sim\mathrm{Laplace}(b)$. As such the upper-bound on the MGF becomes
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{b\lambda X}] \leq e^{2b^2\lambda^2}\text{ for }|b\lambda|<\frac12 \iff \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda bX}] \leq e^{2b^2\lambda^2}\text{ for }|\lambda|<\frac{1}{2b},$$
from which we conclude that the $\mathrm{Laplace}(b)$ distribution is sub-exponential with parameters $\nu=2b, \alpha=2b$.